# Improper integral:- Change of Variable.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$ I=\int _{ -\infty}^{ \infty} \frac{\log(\lvert t\rvert)}{x^4+t^2} \, dt $$

ATTEMPT:- Since the function is even, the following property may be used:

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx=2\int_0^a f(x) \, dx, \text{ if } f(x)=f(-x). \tag 1$$

$$\implies I=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(\lvert t\rvert)}{x^4+t^2} \, dt $$

However if we make use of the following property:

$$\int _a^b f(x) \, dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx. \tag 2$$

For the above integral,
$$  I=\int _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log(\lvert t\rvert)}{x^4+t^2} \, dt $$

$f(a+b-x)=f(\infty -\infty-x )$ which does not exist.

However on substituting $t=x^2\tan\theta$,

$$  I=\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{ \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\log(\lvert x^2\tan\theta\rvert)}{x^2} \, dt $$

$f(a+b-x)=f(\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ exists.

Is this just because my integral has changed to other variable?

Comment: Do you want to know how to calculate this integral? (I have it in my notes) Or do you wonder why you can not always apply the $f(x) = f(a + b - x)$ property? The last follows from that you need to integrate over a finite interval to give meaning to reflection.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar , No, I just want to know in a integral, the same property holds and does not hold too depending on the limits. So do properties of definite integral depend on limits?And is it just because I substituted to get finite limits?

Comment: Yes. How does you prove the identity $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b f(a+b - x) \,\mathrm{d}x$? One way is to use the substitution $x \mapsto a + b - u$ which *only* makes sense **mathematically** when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Lets for simplicity sake say that $a=0$. Then $\int_0^a f(x) = \int_0^a f(a-x)$. Geometrically we now integrate backwards starting at $a$ and working backwards untill zero, this notion of backwardness (or symetry around $(a+b)/2$) loses all meaning when we include infinity.